# Alignment of two different screens connected in dual-screen mode in a system

Tags: java, display, multiple-monitors

When two systems connected in dual mode one system will be the default system and other will extend right to it or to its left.

I want to programmatically find to which side does it extends. How is this found programmatically?

NB: My app runs on Java and I've already tried out the GraphicsEnvironment function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this.

```
GraphicsDevice[] g = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices();
         
for ( GraphicsDevice gd : g) {
     System.out.println(gd.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds());
}
```

The bounds should be representative of the relative position of the screen(s) to each other.

Comment: I suppose this works, let me see and will update here.